# How do I split a column on google sheets into two columns, one with a symbol and the other with a number?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a CSV that's generated from a website which, when imported has a column that looks like this

```
| INR 2000 |

| USD 300  |

| YEN 350  |
```

I would like to separate the currency symbol and the number into separate columns so that it looks like this

```
| INR | 2000 |
| USD | 300  |
| YEN | 350  |
```

Here, the symbol and the amount are in two separate columns. How do I achieve this? I tried going to Data > Split text to columns and all I get is a small popup asking me to specify a seperator. When I do, the number disappears and only the currency symbol remains. Is there anything that I am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If after currency symbol there's space, you can use:

```
=split(a1," ")
```

or if you want to split whole column:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(split(a1:a," ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to paste CSV data as is into the spreadsheet and go to **Data** selecting **Split text to columns...** and even further specifying the delimiter:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

---

Also, you can simply use keyboard shortcut combo:

**<kbd>`LEFT ALT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`D`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`E`</kbd>**

---

And as already mentioned **`SPLIT`** formula:

```
=SPLIT("l,f,x,a,s,f"; ",")
```




```
=SPLIT(A1; ",")
```

For a range/array it would be:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(A1:A; ",")))
```

[image: 0]